# Jones Polynomial as an Equivariant Index

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, khovanov-homology

In Khovanov homology the Jones polynomial of a given link is computed as the graded Euler characteristic of a certain complex associated with the link.  From other side the Atiyah-Singer theorem provides a representation of the Euler characteristic as the index of a certain elliptic operator.  Then my question is : It is possible to obtain the Jones polynomial as the equivariant index of a certain Dirac operator associated with the given  link?

Comment: Euler characteristic is one of the most heavily interpreted concepts in topology, with a variant for essentially every interest. Is there something motivating this particular question?

Comment: Note that the complex whose Euler characteristic gives rise to the Jones polynomial is not the same as the complex whose Euler characteristic is computed by the index of the de Rham operator (namely, the de Rham complex).  I don't have a reason why the Jones polynomial is *not* related to the index theorem somehow, but "both involve Euler characteristics of complexes" is not convincing evidence to me.

Comment: Simon Willerton has written about a rough analogue of your question for the Kontsevich Invariant: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105190

Comment: Professor @DanielMoskovich many thanks for the paper which is very interesting.  From other side your papers about tangle machines are impressive.  All the best.

Comment: A recent paper very close to the answer  of my question is   http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/1502.03116.pdf